# Wpf Toolkit Line Chart not displaying data

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm currently trying to add a Line Chart to my Application using the wpf toolkit.

The chart itself shows up without a problem, but the data is not displayed. 
If I set a breakpoint to look at the data, I can clearly see, that the Observable Collection is populated with the desired data.

This is the Chart in my XAML:

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="Gehtdas" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <charting:Chart.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="charting:Chart.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=TypeSelection, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Line_Chart">
                        <Setter Property="charting:Chart.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </charting:Chart.Style>
        <charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:LinearAxis Title="Tyres" Orientation="Y" Interval="100" Visibility="Visible" Maximum="1000" Minimum="0"/>
            <charting:DateTimeAxis x:Name="TimeAxis" Title="Time" Orientation="X"/>                
        </charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LineSeries DataContext="{Binding}" Title="Tyres per Interval" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" ItemsSource="{Binding LineChartValues}" 
                             IsSelectionEnabled="True" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" />
    </charting:Chart>
```

LineChartValues is a KeyValuePair Observable Collection like this.

```
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime?, decimal?>> _lineChartValues;
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime?, decimal?>> LineChartValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineChartValues;
        }
        set
        {
            _lineChartValues = value;
        }
    }
```

The Viewmodel is bound via ISite to the xaml.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm pretty desperate by now and would really appreciate any help.

EDIT:
If I delete the DataContext={Binding} part I get a NullReferenceException while populating the Observable Collection.

EDIT2: Population of Values in window loaded:
Xaml:

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="Gehtdas" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <!--<charting:Chart.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="charting:Chart.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=TypeSelection, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Line_Chart">
                        <Setter Property="charting:Chart.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </charting:Chart.Style>-->
        <charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:LinearAxis Title="Tyres" Orientation="Y" Interval="100" Visibility="Visible" Maximum="1000" Minimum="0"/>
            <charting:DateTimeAxis x:Name="TimeAxis" Title="Time" Orientation="X"/>                
        </charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LineSeries Title="Tyres per Interval" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                             IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
    </charting:Chart>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>> valueList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>>();
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // workaround for Bug in DateTimeAxis which causes the Axis to divide the Default IntervalType of Year into given IntervalType and Interval. 
        //Setting the IntervalType and Interval this way, prevents it from calculating the interval for a whole year.
        this.TimeAxis.Minimum = new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 0, 0, 0);
        this.TimeAxis.Maximum = new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 16, 0, 0);
        //this.TimeAxis.Minimum = DateTime.Now.Date;
        //this.TimeAxis.Maximum = DateTime.Now;
        this.TimeAxis.IntervalType = System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
        this.TimeAxis.Interval = 1;

        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>(new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 10, 0, 0), 60));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>(new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 11, 0, 0), 40));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>(new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 12, 0, 0), 50));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>(new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 13, 0, 0), 30));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int?>(new DateTime(2016, 02, 10, 14, 0, 0), 40));
        Gehtdas.DataContext = valueList;
    }
```

EDIT 3: Here comes the Exception Stacktrace:

```
   at 

System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineAreaBaseSeries`1.UpdateDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.OnDataPointActualIndependentValueChanged(DataPoint dataPoint, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnDataPointActualIndependentValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnActualIndependentValuePropertyChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnActualIndependentValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.set_ActualIndependentValue(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.OnDataPointIndependentValueChanged(DataPoint dataPoint, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineAreaBaseSeries`1.OnDataPointIndependentValueChanged(DataPoint dataPoint, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnDataPointIndependentValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnIndependentValuePropertyChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnIndependentValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateTreeDependentProperty(TreeChangeInfo info, DependencyObject d, FrameworkObject& fo, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkPropertyMetadata fMetadata, Style selfStyle, Style selfThemeStyle, ChildRecord& childRecord, Boolean isChildRecordValid, Boolean hasStyleChanged, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateTreeDependentProperties(TreeChangeInfo info, FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style selfStyle, Style selfThemeStyle, ChildRecord& childRecord, Boolean isChildRecordValid, Boolean hasStyleChanged, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateTreeDependentProperties(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.InsertInternal(Int32 index, UIElement element)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.AddDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.AddObject(Object dataContext)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.LoadDataPoints(IEnumerable newItems, IEnumerable oldItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.Refresh()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject contextElement)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnInheritablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, InheritablePropertyChangeInfo info, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnInheritablePropertyChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, InheritablePropertyChangeInfo info, Boolean skipStartNode)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Mfc.Statistic.StoragePerformance.MainWindow_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in d:\Source_Wista\2014-103141 GDC Bridgestone Burgos Materialfluss\MFC-Solution\Mfc\Statistic\StoragePerformance.xaml.cs:line 91
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at Wista.App.Main() in d:\Source_Wista\Wista\Wista\obj\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
```

EDIT4:

So I tried the simple static data approach in a new empty solution and there it works. I guess the problem lies in some conflict between the toolkit and some other framework.

Comment: In your `Style`, you're setting `Chart.Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Comment: Yep, the whole chart is set to Collapsed, but when I select the correct value in the Combobox, it shows up. As I said, the problem is not the chart itself, but the data not showing up.

Comment: I see chart data once i remove that line from the style....

Comment: Also, i load the view model on main window `Loaded` event.

Comment: Ok, that's weird, if I remove that line I get a NullReferenceException while populating the Observable Collection...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Binding, it works. The problem seems to be this `ISite` you mentioned. Just try to loaded data in your view model at the `Loaded` event of your main window. That's what i did.

Comment: Hmm.. well, this is only part of a bigger file, where all the bindings rely on the ISite Interface.

Comment: Well, `ISite` itself may not be the problem. The problem seems to be that you're loading data at a point in time where your components are not ready for it (`NullReferenceException` you mentioned). The main window's `Loaded` event is a safe place to populate your view model.

Comment: Ok, I populated the data in the this.Loaded event, but I still get the Exception when I declare the Datacontext (in the window loaded event).

Comment: When you **declare** the `DataContext`? You don't have to declare anything, you have to assign it with your view model.... Please post your code showing when and how you're populating your view model and assigning it to `DataContext`.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I meant to write assign ^^.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Made an edit to OP

Comment: Also, if you're getting an exception, please post full stack trace of it.

Comment: The stack trace is really damn long. I added it.

Comment: I added all of your code and it still works fine. As for the exception, unfortunately doesn't help much because is coming from `App.g.cs`, which is generated by the build environment.... Sounds like something got corrupted in your project. Try to `Clean` and then `Rebuild`.

Comment: hmm, damn, thank you anyways, for your effort. Clean and rebuild also doesn't work...

Comment: One last thing: note your code and your binding are kind of inconsistent now after all changes. In your XAML you're binding to `LineChartValues`, which supposedly is a property of your `ViewModel`. But in your code behind you assign `valueList`, which is an `ObservableCollection`, to your `DataContext`. You don't show where this variable comes from and you don't show anything about your view model. It is difficult to troubleshoot when you're not accurate with your code.....

Comment: I added the modified xaml in the edit with the static Value assignment.

Comment: OK, just know that your code worked for me, so the problem is "somewhere else".

Comment: Yeah, I just tried Vitalyik's code in a new empty solution and that works. I'm going to go crazy here ^^

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that chart doesn't know how to display your Nullable values(DateTime?, decimal?). You probably need a converter that will exctract the value from Nullable decorator.

Here's my example:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfToolkitChart.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1031" Width="855" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,-28,0,28">
        <Grid Height="921">

            <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Line Series Demo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="33,611,440,0" Height="254">
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfToolkitChart
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      showColumnChart();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int?>> valueList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int?>>();

    private void showColumnChart()
    {

      valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("Developer",60));
      valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("Misc", 20));
      valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("Tester", 50));
      valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("QA", 30));
      valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("Project Manager", 40));

      //Setting data for line chart
      lineChart.DataContext = valueList;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried a quick and dirty solution by implicitly casting it to non-nullable values (as I know the current values aren't null), but this didn't work.

Comment: Than there is a problem with your binding: DataContext={Binding} and ItemsSource="{Binding LineChartValues}"  seems strange for me also. Where is LineChartValues declared? Is it in ViewModel or in View?

Comment: In the ViewModel. DataContext should be inherited from the xaml Binding itself, am I right. So I could just leave it in the chart declaration.

Comment: Try this: DataContext="{Binding LineChartValues}" and ItemsSource="{Binding}". I have working example where list is declared in view and binds to chart datacontext directly.

Comment: Doesn't work either (I think I tried it already). I get this error if I do this: System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=LineChartValues; DataItem=null; target element is 'LineSeries' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: Maybe you need to RaisePropertyChanged while setting the property LineChartValues?

Comment: No, also doesn't do the trick. But I have a new thing discovered. When I do it Without DataContext={Binding} and only set the ItemsSource, I get a NullReferenceException while populating the LineChartValues. So I guess, it does bind, it just doesn't display it.

Comment: Thank you. If I do it like you did it, I get a NullReferenceException somewhere in the toolkit.

Comment: I compiled this example with 3.5.50211.1 version of WpfToolkit.

Comment: Well, my version is 3.5.40128.1. Weird, I downloaded the NuGet a couple days ago. Wait. the version of the actual dll that is referenced is the same as yours. Just VS Properties are displaying the older version... I'm confused.

Comment: Strange thing. Maybe there is some conflict between WPFToolkit and some other frameworks that you are using. Don't know what else to  say but what I supposed to do in  your situation - get chart working in  the simple case(with  static data for example) and than incrementally modify the code to catch the thing which is breaking the functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried to get it to work with simple static data, but even that is not working, for I get a NullReferenceException as soon as I assign the Datacontext.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right, I just tried your code in a new empty solution and it works fine. That's some crazy shit...

Comment: Try than to move the list from View into  ViewModel and see what happens. As it always happen in WPF - one small mistake in binding etc can break the whole thing without any visible errors)

Comment: Well, I tried it in a new empty solution. So I guess, the problem lies somewhere else. Some incompatibility with another framework as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the Language property of your chart to "en-US"

I had got problem with German culture, and I found this solution